# Python changing a small part of the function

Tags: python

The purpose of this function is to encrypt and decrypt a text message:

```
def program(str):
    i = 0
    message = []
    while i < len(str):
        message.append(ord(str[i]))
        i += 1
    print(message)
program (text)
```

Is it possible to change the `ord()` call so I do not have to create a completely new function? Sort of like the `str` where I can re-enter a new string every single time I run the function.

Comment: What shoukd the programm do in the end?

Comment: As you might be able to tell from the 3 very different answers, your question is quite unclear as written. Consider editing it to make it more obvious exactly what you're looking for (a good start is including example input and desired output).

Answer (score 1):

I believe I understand what you want here. You want to be able to call `program` so it runs `ord` on each character in your string, but you also want to be able to run (for instance) `chr` on each character in your string without having to make a whole new function called `program_chr`.

Happily, Python supports [first-class functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function), so this is definitely possible. You can just pass a function as an argument to `program`, just as easily as you pass a string.

```
def program (my_str, my_fn):
    i = 0
    message = []
    while i<len(my_str):
        message.append(my_fn(my_str[i]))
        i += 1
    print(message)

program("my_string", ord)
```

This outputs `[109, 121, 95, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103]`, without `ord` ever appearing in `program`!

You can use any function for this, including ones you define yourself:

```
def silly_fn (char):
    return 12

program("my_string", silly_fn)
```

This outputs `[12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12]`.

---

Relevant note: I changed the parameter `str` to `my_str`, because `str` is a built-in function, and it's never good practice to redefine those without good reason!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I did not interpret the question correctly; the wording is a bit confusing. I am assuming that when you said "completely new function", you meant "completely new loop". If you are asking whether or not it's possible to ditch the while loop completely, as far as I know, it is not possible. It is possible to use a for loop though.

```
for i in range(len(str)):
    message.append(ord(str[i]))
```

Again, sorry if I misinterpreted your question.

Answer (score 0):

You question is not very clear but are you looking something like this ?

```
def program (str):
    i, j = 0, 0
    message = []
    for i in range(len(str)):
      while j<len(str[i]):
        message.append(ord(str[i][j]))
        j += 1
    print(message)

text1 = 'This is test1'
text2 = 'This is test2'
text3 = 'This is test3'
text4 = 'This is test4'

str_list = [text1,text2,text3,text4]

program (str_list)
```

This outputs

```
[84, 104, 105, 115, 32, 105, 115, 32, 116, 101, 115, 116, 49]
```